# How do I install AMD Drivers on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, ati, catalyst

I was planning on doing a Windows build but I had problems getting Daz to work so I'm here now.  I'm trying to download the proprietary drivers for my AMD Radeon HD 6870 but nothing is working.  I tried following videos but things happen differently on my computer.  Also, I tried updating it through the additional drivers screen but it said I had to reboot my computer to finish then when it rebooted it went into low graphics mode.  Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open up the terminal and type the following. It will ask for your password and to confirm it

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```